# Why is this simple python PIR motion sensor script using so much CPU power?

Tags: raspbian, python, sensor

I have a simple script I found that I'm using to deactivate xscreensaver via PIR motion sensor.  It's using nearly 40% of my CPU when it runs.  How can I calm it down?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(17): # Waits for motion signal from PIR on GPIO pin 17 then complete rest and exit
        print ("deactivating screensaver")
        os.system("xscreensaver-command -deactivate")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are looping as fast as the CPU can process the loop. Try adding a sleep to back off the CPU. It is unlikely that you need to check the motion sensor as often as you are

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(17): # Waits for motion signal from PIR on GPIO pin 17 then complete rest and exit
        print ("deactivating screensaver")
        os.system("xscreensaver-command -deactivate")
    time.sleep(1) # sleeps for 1 second
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with this but isn't there a possibility with exceptions?

Comment: @ingo possibility of what?

Comment: I mean, maybe there is a way to use [exceptions in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) instead of polling with sleep. I don't know if RPi.GPIO can raise exceptions, maybe with use of built-in Exceptions?

Comment: @Ingo: No... Exceptions are for when bad things happen. The keyword you're looking for is _interrupts_.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Yes, in higher programming languages _interrupts_ are called _exception_ because there is more done than interrupt a program flow by the cpu, jump to a interrupt vector and push the program status to the stack ;-) And exceptions not only used for error conditions. But we get off topic ...

Comment: @Ingo: [No](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

Comment: @Jacobm001 OK, `signal`. But back to the question (it isn't mine): how can this used to reduce cpu time without _polling_ and _sleep_? That was the idea.